# Implementing Vue RESTful API calls in Django within Django Templates with Session Authentication

Tags: python, django, vue.js, vue-resource

I have a Django project that requires page refreshes any time I want to update the content. Currently it uses the built in Django Class Based Views, which in turn use Templates.

I want to start implementing some javascript calls to refresh tables/forms/modal windows with new data, mostly in response to button clicks. I'm trying to use Vue to accomplish this, and I have created a Django REST Framework backend to facilitate this.

I got a simple 'Hello world' vue class working where the data is hard coded into the data field of the Vue class. I can't seem to make the jump to getting data from the API though. I am getting an Unauthorized response. I am using vue-resource for the HTTP API call.

I have unit tests where I call the API from the DRF APITestCase using the self.client.get('api/path') and they work as expected (unauthorized when there is no authenticated user attached to request, authorized when there is).

I have debugged into the DRF Permission class to see why the request is being refused and it is because there is no authenticated User attached to the request.

I have added SessionAuthentication to the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES in settings.

My question is, how do I add an authenticated user to the request so that when the Vue method is called from within my webapp the API request will be authorized?

I'm not sure if this is complicating matters but I am using a custom user model within Django for authentication.

I am hoping to start off by implementing a few Vue controls throughout my website, for instance the tables and forms mentioned. I don't want to turn this into a single page app. I would like to continue using the Django views for user authentication.

My Vue code looks like so;

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}$'],
    el: '.events-table',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        demo: [
            { id: 5 },
            { id: 2 },
            { id: 3 },
        ],
        events: [],
    },
    http: {
        root: 'http://localhost:8000',
    },
    methods: {
        getEvents: function () {
            this.$http.get('api/eventlog/events/?format=json').then(
                function (data, status, request) {
                    if (status == 200) {
                        this.events = data.body.results;
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getEvents();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the http property like so

```
http: {
    root: window.location.origin,
},
```

and now it seems to recognise that the request is coming from an authenticated session.